# Is It Possible To Create A WEB SITE With HTML PAGES But With Some Auxiliary PHP PAGES?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, programming-languages, hybrid

I know the basics of  HTML and JAVASCRIPT, but I know almost nothing about PHP. 
I want to build a simple web site with one or two HTML web pages ( actually I already made those pages and tested them in my PC but without the sign up functionality and related database ) and one or two pages for a sign up/ sign in form page so that I could save the data from my visitors or subscribers. I actually would prefer this user registration page to appear in a popup window instead of sending him to another page and leaving the principal. So that, when he finishes filling the form, this form windows would close and he would remain in the same page. I read that Wordpress can easily create these forms, their code and also the correspondent database ( mySQL ) but the pages it builds are PHP ones. So, is it possible a popup window form made with Wordpress php code to jump in front of a page made with HTML ?

( I already created the home page with HTML, CSS and javascript.)

Comment: You may want to look at services that provide embedded forms. They store the data and manage it for you and all you have to do is copy/paste a snippet of HTML/Javascript into your page.

Comment: you can use js for opening popup models, AJAX for sending data into database using PHP. [See more here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)

Comment: If you want to use wordpress, then there's custom login forms available there. You just need to enable and use them. And if you want a custom coded login form, use Ajax to fetch the login.php file and display it in popup window. Also use Ajax to send the login data to login_parse.php page and validate them.